# Multiple $stateParams causing controller to be called multiple times

Tags: angularjs

I have a stateProvider which looks like:

```
$stateProvider.state('test.example', {
        url: '/test?param1&param2',
        templateUrl: 'test/testParam.html',
        controller: 'testParamCtrl'
});
```

When I console log $stateParams in my controller, it runs twice. This happens only when I'm switching between tabs on my app. This problem doesn't occur if I refresh the app.

It seems as if the controller is "building" the stateParams object and instantiating the controller each time. Therefore, I'm getting some angular errors of param2 being undefined during the first instantiation. This is what the console logs look like:

```
Object {param1: "data1", param2: undefined} // first instantiation
Object {param1: "data1", param2: "data2"} // second instantiation
```

When I refresh the page, however, only one console log shows up, which is the "correct one" (i.e. param1 and param2 are both defined).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create a [mcve] demo in plunker that replicates this

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that in `'test/testParam.html'` you have `ng-controller="testParamCtrl"`. Remove `ng-controller` in the template or remove the controller property in your state definition.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your state defination to:

```
$stateProvider.state('test.example', {
        url: '/test/:param1/:param2',
        templateUrl: 'test/testParam.html',
        controller: 'testParamCtrl'
});
```

to pass parameters in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign parameter values

```
   $stateProvider.state('test.example', {
    url: '/test/:param1/:param2',
     params: { 
     param1: "data1",  
    param2: "data2"  }
    templateUrl: 'test/testParam.html',
    controller: 'testParamCtrl'});
```